# BeautifulSoup doesn't scrape all the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all the comments in french on this website for all the pages (807) : https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/www.gammvert.fr

There are 16 121 comments in total (in french).

Here's my script :

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


root_url = 'https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/www.gammvert.fr'
urls = [ '{root}?page={i}'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in range(1,808) ]

comms = []
notes = []

for url in urls: 
    results = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    commentary = soup.find_all('section', class_='review__content')

    for container in commentary:

        try:
            comm  = container.find('p', class_ = 'review-content__text').text.strip()

        except:
            comm = container.find('a', class_ = 'link link--large link--dark').text.strip()

        comms.append(comm)

        note = container.find('div', class_ = 'star-rating star-rating--medium').find('img')['alt']
        notes.append(note)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes
    })

data['comms'] = data['comms'].str.replace('\n', '')


#print(data.head())
data.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

But unfortunately, this script got me only 7261 comments as you could see here : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYxFo.png)

And I don't see why I couldn't obtain all the comments ? The script doesn't give me any error whatsoever so I'm kind of lost.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely "rate-limited" by the website, so after 100+ call from the same IP address they start to block you and don't send back any data. Your program doesn't notice that because

```py
for container in commentary:
    # all the rest
```

doesn't do anything since `commentary` at this point is = `[]`. You can check that by printing `len(commentary)`

You can check on the website what the rate limit is and add a `time.sleep()` accordingly in your loop. Alternatively, you can check that `results == '<Response [200]>'` otherwise use `time.sleep(several minutes)` to delay the next request call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it out :)

Comment: I put the time.sleep() like that :                                                                                                          
    for url in urls: 
 results = requests.get(url)

 time.sleep(50)

 soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")                                                  The script is running right now, how would you put it in the code you ? Because I don't think it's the optimal way, it's very long.

Comment: And also how I check the wbesite rate limit ?

Comment: You can check https://developers.trustpilot.com/ for rate limit, however it seems they are not stating it. You can try ```time.sleep(1)``` or even smaller value, because 50 is too extreme. Finally, you could also consider using their public API. In general I would strongly recommend using API vs scraping the data yourself, if the API option is available.

Comment: Everyone tell me about those API but I don't really understand how to do that and where ? Could you explain if you have the time plz ? :)

Comment: When you type a URL in your browser you are requesting the full html content of a webpage, which you then have to parse to extract the data you are interested in. An API allows you to request specific data that is already well structured in json format, so you don't have to parse anything. For your example it would be useful because you would not have to go through 800 different pages to get all the reviews, but instead you would use the API function to get all reviews for a specific business. I suggest you check what APIs are on Youtube or blog posts.

Comment: Thank but you misunderstood me. I know what an API is and what purpose they have. i just don't know where to find her and how to find her. :)

Comment: Either use the website API directly (developers.trustpilot.com) or check if someone has already developed a python module that wraps the API. It looks like there's one https://pypi.org/project/trustpilot/